# Delphi Reverse order of bytes

Tags: delphi, pointers, byte, reverse

I have been trying to write a function that takes two pointers (an input and an output) and writes the bytes from the input into the output in reverse order.  So far I have not been able to make it work correctly.

```
procedure ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Move(Pointer(LongInt(Source) + Index)^, Pointer(LongInt(Dest) + (Size - Index))^ , 1);   
end;
```

Can anyone please suggest a better way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd bet that you don't actually want to reverse bytes. What you probably want to do is convert from host byte order to network byte order. There are functions in all comms library for that. Use them. It will make your code more logically accurate. It's like the difference between div 2 and shr 1. It will also save headaches when you put your code on a big endian machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  for Index := 0 to Size - 1 do
    Move(Pointer(LongInt(Source) + Index)^, 
        Pointer(LongInt(Dest) + (Size - Index - 1))^ , 1);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: AnsiString;
  P: Pointer;
begin
  s := #0'testreverse';
  GetMem(P, Length(s));
  ReverseBytes(Pointer(s), P, Length(s));

  ShowMessage(PAnsiChar(P));   // esrevertset
  FreeMem(P);
end;
```

Comment: I wonder why call whole Move routine instead of simple byte assigning - didactic purposes? And small correction - ShowMessage(PAnsiChar(P)) would be better for Unicode versions of Delphi.

Comment: @MBo - My intention was to help identify the problem with the original code.. Thanks for the PAnsiChar correction.

Comment: -1 Using Move() with a size of 1!!!! Just awful for me. Even if the OP used it. It was not the point here.

Comment: @Arnaud - It **is** the point here. I also explained it in the comment prior to yours. Someone is having such a basic trouble, the foremost important thing is that he identifies what's wrong with it. Anyway, I appreciate your commenting..

Comment: Another issue: you should better use 64 bit ready pointer arithmetic here, e.g. using `move(PAnsiChar(Source)[Index],PAnsiChar(Dest)[Size-Index-1],1)` - or even better `PAnsiChar(Dest)[Size-Index-1] := PAnsiChar(Source)[Index]` and not the un-compatible `longint(Source)`.

Comment: @Arnaud - You don't seem to understand why I didn't modify the original code as much as I can in the question at all, despite how I try and tell. You've given your vote and I'm not interested in your micro optimizations or future readiness, for the reasons I've already told. But of course you may continue if you believe people will find great value with your comments.

Answer (score 7):

```
procedure ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
begin
  Dest := PByte( NativeUInt(Dest) + Size - 1);
  while (Size > 0) do 
  begin
    PByte(Dest)^ := PByte(Source)^;
    Inc(PByte(Source));
    Dec(PByte(Dest));
    Dec(Size);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 Clear, fast and efficient. Another faster pattern could be to reverse bytes by two (from both ends), up to the middle. But much better than the other implementation.