# What to use instead of "ReverseBytes"?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, delphi-10-seattle

With XE8 (no changes in Seattle), `ReverseBytes` has moved from `FMX.Types` to `FMX.Utils` and is marked as deprecated. The function takes a buffer and reverses the order of its bytes. Why has it been marked as deprecated, and what other function should be used instead?

Comment: Most likely deprecated because it's a dirty low-level method with no type safety and there are better ways to solve the types of problems you would typically use it for.  What are you trying to do?  Is this a host-to-network byte order problem?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you feel the need to call this function in the first place?

Comment: I am reading a double (big endian) from a stream to a buffer, reverse the byte order and then access the memory as double.

Comment: Then you are using the wrong function. You need to convert from network to host. Which happens to be identical for this specific host. Find a 64 bit network to host function. Surely there's one in the rtl.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is that network/host conversion function? A quick Google shows nothing - either a custom-rolled method, or using `ReverseBytes`, the method the OP is asking about. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966182/delphi-reverse-order-of-bytes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505211/how-to-convert-a-record-from-host-to-network-byte-order-big-endian

Comment: @DavidM Functions like ntohs, ntohl and so on.

Comment: Thank you. If somebody wants to post that as the reason for deprecating the function I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The [Windows functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740075(v=vs.85).aspx)? In other words, there's no Delphi RTL method?

Comment: @DavidM: if there are functions that work, but are provided by the OS on each of the platforms, why not? Or is your question a case of NIH?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No, it's a case of wanting a cross-platform RTL. Ie, write code once, have it work on Windows / OSX / etc. Something like network byte order seems the sort of thing it would be good to have in the RTL available for all platforms.

Comment: @DavidM: Functions like `ntohl()`, `htonl()`, etc. are, AFAIK, available on most platforms. IIRC, they are POSIX functions. So I don't see the need for Delphi to define their own.