# Swapping order of bytes in Delphi

Tags: delphi, byte, reverse, endianness

I'm not very familiar with arrays of bite and big/little endians but I need to write an integer value into byte array in reverse and I don't know how to do it in Delphi code. C# has BitConverter.Reverse methong which is so much easier, is there any equivalent for it in Delphi?
This is my code so far:

```
x := 1500977838953;
setLength(byteArray, 8);
Move(x, byteArray[2], SizeOf(x));
showMessage(ByteToHex(byteArray));
```

ByteToHex is a method that returns me hex string so I can read the bytes if they are in correct order. The result that I am getting is : `0000693B40795D01` but I need it to be: `00-00-01-5D-79-40-3B-69`

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Edit:

```
function ByteToHex(b: array of byte): String;
const HexSymbols = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 2*Length(b));
  for i :=  0 to Length(b)-1 do begin
    Result[1 + 2*i + 0] := HexSymbols[1 + b[i] shr 4];
    Result[1 + 2*i + 1] := HexSymbols[1 + b[i] and $0F];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Actually yes I did, and found this procedure `procedure ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
begin
  Dest := PByte( NativeUInt(Dest) + Size - 1);
  while (Size > 0) do 
  begin
    PByte(Dest)^ := PByte(Source)^;
    Inc(PByte(Source));
    Dec(PByte(Dest));
    Dec(Size);
  end;
end;` but im unsure how should i use it in my example here. Thank you for answering, im kinda new to delphi code.

Comment: @q1werty What exactly is ByteToHex? What you need to reverse actually?

Comment: I edited the question, added function to read the order of bytes. All i need to do is write the bytes in reverse, that's it. X is the value, and I need the order of bytes to be `00-00-01-5D-79-40-3B-69`. Easy question, tough to solve, atleast for me.

Comment: @q1werty if I understand you correctly - you have Int64 value and you want to write its bytes in an array in exact yours order? If that's the case - I would solve it by making your own function which will put the corresponding byte of Int64 value into desired index in byte array. Or you can use that procedure you already found - just your "byte array" can be another Int64 variable and call it something like `ReverseBytes(@YourVar, @ReversedVar, 8)`

Comment: Thank you for answering kind sir but not a single word was understood there, I'm new to delphi and i got no idea how to write the code that you just tried to explain. If you could provide an example code it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @q1werty Andreas was not evaluating your personality, and your reaction to that was out of order. What is especially odd about this question is that you yourself provided the answer in a comment above. I cannot understand why you didn't just call the function that you posted in your comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Maybe my question was a bit out of order as well, I should have asked for the proper way to call that function, apparently I called it the wrong way. That's why I asked for an example. Wasn't sure if that function was the right one for my problem.

Comment: Another time I would suggest that you include your code, with how you are trying to call it. I think that would have helped in this case. That would also give us an opportunity to point out what your misunderstanding was and help you learn more. But please don't ask people to leave, especially not @AndreasRejbrand who is categorically a very helpful and kind member of this community.

Comment: Noted. I didn't include the code because I felt like it wouldn't have helped much at all, I did not understand the pointer parameters completely, now I do. Asking this question here wasn't impulsive, I've been googling about it for 2 days. His comment wasn't in its place here anyhow, no matter how kind he is, it wasn't helpful. We all make mistakes. I really appreciate you taking time to make things right. I'll do better next time. Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to use the [ReverseBytes()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969282/576719) procedure:

```
program Project20;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
begin
  Dest := PByte(NativeUInt(Dest) + Size - 1);
  while (Size > 0) do
  begin
    PByte(Dest)^ := PByte(Source)^;
    Inc(PByte(Source));
    Dec(PByte(Dest));
    Dec(Size);
  end;
end;

var x,y : Int64;

begin
  x := 1500977838953;
  WriteLn(x);
  ReverseBytes(Addr(x),Addr(y),SizeOf(x)); // Or ReverseBytes(@x,@y,SizeOf(x));
  WriteLn(IntToHex(x));
  WriteLn(IntToHex(y));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Output:

```
1500977838953
0000015D79403B69
693B40795D010000
```

To get the address of a variable, use the `Addr()` function or the `@` operator.
The result is a 64-bit integer with all bytes in reversed order, as shown by the output.

There are other ways to swap the byte order of a variable. Search for `bswap` for example.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I was apparently calling for the wrong pointer and reading byte array the way I shouldn't have. This makes it more clearer now. Thank you very much!